# Multiple problems regarding MapStruct mapping

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct, object-object-mapping

I am new to using MapStruct and thus facing some issues with the same.

I have the following Model classes :-

```
@Data
class User {

@Field
private String fullName;

@Field("experience")
private List<Experience> workExperience;

//other fields

}

@Data
class Experience {

private Date joiningDate;

//other fields
}
```

Now, I have the following DTO's

```
@Data
class UserDTO {

 private String firstName;

 private String lastName;

 private List<ExperienceDTO> workExperience;

 //other fields

}

@Data
class ExperienceDTO {

private String joiningDate;

//other fields
}
```

Have written the UserMapper Interface as :-

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

 @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "firstName",source = "fullName",
                    qualifiedByName = "firstNameExtractor"),
            @Mapping(target = "lastName",source = "fullName",
                    qualifiedByName = "lastNameExtractor")
    })
    UserDTO userToUserDTO(User user);

  @Mappings({
      @Mapping(target = "joiningDate", source = "joiningDate",
              dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    })
    List<ExperienceDTO> experienceToExperienceDTO(List<Experience> experience);

@Named("firstNameExtractor")
    public static String getFirstName(String name){
        String[] nameParts = name.split(" ");
        return nameParts[0];
    }
//similarly have a lastNameExtractor
```

But I get the following errors :-

1. No property named "fullName" exists in source parameter(s). Did you
   mean "null"?
2. Unknown property "firstName" in result type
   com.personal.portfolio.dto.UserDTO. Did you mean "null"?
3. No property named "joiningDate" exists in source parameter(s). Did
   you mean empty"?
4. Unknown property "joiningDate" in result type
   java.util.List. Did you
   mean "empty"?

I know my design might be wrong, but I am intentionally doing it this way to understand how MapStruct works. Kindly anyone could help me to understand what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Have you also generated Getter / Setters?

Comment: Yes using Lombok. I have added the @Data annotation.

Comment: Okay, I could get rid of the errors related to firstName, by adding lombok artifact to <annotationProcessorPaths> of lombok. But the problem related to Date still persists.

Comment: But as I can see you are passing date format to non-date type in actual you have string type not date can you try to change it to date or something ?

Comment: I want to convert my Date(in model) to String(in DTO). I followed reference from this tutorial :-

https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct#Type

Comment: Creating getter and setters from the class that you are getting the reference, do the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first error is because MapStruct does not see Lombok annotated methods.
Add the annotation processor to the build:

```
                   <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
```

The second is that you add @Mapping to the list of objects, not the object itself. Create a method, which map a single Experience to ExperienceDTO, add the annotation there and remove it from the experienceToExperienceDTO method.

Answer (score 4):

add the following tag to "maven-compiler-plugin" plugin

```
<configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
</configuration>
```

Comment: lombok-mapstruct-binding works like charms thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally I could solve the errors and here are the solution to both the problems :-

1. As mentioned by @Zlaval I needed to add the annotation processor to the build of MapStruct to get rid of the error related to FirstName.
2. And to map List to List we donot need a method 
   `List<DTOObject> entityListToDTOList(List<EntityObject> entity)`

only, a single Entity to DTO mapped method with `@Mappings` annotation(if required) will be enough.